# How to capture/track the app shortcut icon click event?

Tags: ionic3, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a ionic 3 app. It has deep-linking and push notifications. How could I know, whether the app is opening by clicking the app icon or clicked via any other external link?

Answer (score 0):

You have not explained how you have implemented deep-linking (show your code) but I assume you used this plugin: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/deeplinks

When you implement deeplinking there's an event that is triggered when the app has been opened via link:

```
this.deeplinks.route({
     '/about-us': AboutPage

   }).subscribe(match => {
     // match.$route - the matched route
     // match.$args - args passed in the link
     
     // Here do something

   }, nomatch => {
     console.error('Got a deeplink that didn\'t match', nomatch);
   });
```

Now if what you want to know is how to "remember" later that the app was opened by a link, just put that value in a Service, since services have a single instance that is kept through all the app execution, and any variable stored in a service will be available everywhere, so:

```
.subscribe(match => {
     // match.$route - the matched route
     // match.$args - args passed in the link
     
     myAppService.openByLink = true;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. As you mentioned, I  have written the same thing. But what about Push? Both the push and deep linking is working fine for me. How could I know, whether the app is opening by clicking the app icon or clicked via any other external link?

Comment: Push notifications are implemented using other plugins, and would use a different callback. The code I posted above is only for external links. But in any case, push notifications can carry data, so just add some data to push notifications when sending them from the server.